Hydraulic brakes worked just fine until I switched them to another bike
Hydraulic brakes worked just fine until I switched them to another bike. Now every time I squeeze them they seem to stay compressed but my lever releases.
Hydraulic brakes when squeezed stay compressed but lever releases and back wheel is hard to spin.

Are the calipers aligned properly on their mounts?  Or did you have to do anything to get them to bolt down ?

Did you reset the disc brake caliper pistons? Push them all the way in. I’ve also heard that they can get stuck and pushing them back in can make them move properly again.

When you switched them, did you undo any of the hoses? If so, air has got into the system and is being compressed when you squeeze the levers. The solution is bleeding them.
Parktool have great instructional videos - e.g. How to bleed SRam brakes. Search up the correct video for your brand and style of brakes.
